# React Native - Using iOS and Android SDKs

Tags: react-native

I just started using React Native a few days ago and want to build my next iOS/Android app with it. However, I had a question (and I apologize in advance if this question is very basic).

If I am integrating my iOS and Android apps built with React Native, with an external service (like Salesforce for example), how do I go about using the [native mobile SDKs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK) they provide for iOS and Android? As in, what do I do to integrate those SDKs into my React Native app? Those SDKs are using native Objective-C and Java code, so how would I be able to use the JS code for React Native? I believe my understanding about this is skewed.

I looked at [this link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) which goes into it, but it seemed very confusing and I had a bit of a hard time grasping the concept (again, I am very new to this - I've done a lot of web development, hence turning my attention to React Native, but I've done no mobile development whatsoever).

If someone could please explain how that works, and point me in the right direction where I can read and learn more, I would sincerely appreciate that!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out this talk on [SalesForce mobile SDK for React native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY2vn2bT6XU)

Official SalesForce Docs - [Read Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/react_native_samples.htm)

Also this tutorial might help you. http://rajaraodv.github.io/salesforce-react-native-tutorial/

**Update:**
There are react native packages build by open react native community if you couldn't find anything to access native iOS or android functionality you will have to write react native wrapper yourself using react native "Native Modules"

- [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I was using SalesForce as an example - I was actually looking for a general way to learn how to use external SDKs with React Native application; especially SDKs that leverage the phone's camera, microphone, touch sensor, etc.